# Is there a word which describes "one of many"?

Tags: word-choice

Are there any words that have this meaning? 
One of many, as in a person out of many people.

Clarification:
The single individual or item is similar to the group and not unique in any way.

Comment: Do you mean that the one is the same as the many, or different?

Comment: It would be helpful to have a sample sentence where you want to use the word or words in question. As it stands, I'm not sure if you mean the person is one of a group and is similar to the group, or if they stand out as being different from the group.

Comment: @Lawrence same, similar and not unique.

Comment: A *clone*, perhaps?

Comment: @Lawrence similar not identical, one person out of many people is not exactly a clone but interesting direction.

Comment: Then maybe a [*cog*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cog-in-the-wheel).

Comment: @Lawrence could you please elaborate? AFAIK cog is a metal wheel thing.

Comment: I've added a link to my previous comment.

Comment: You **need** to add a sample sentence, because as it stands "clone" still fits. And if you're looking for a word that  fits with people and inanimate objects this too must be clarified.

Comment: At present you haven't said if you're looking for a noun (such as **pleb**) or an adjective (such as **ordinary**). You also haven't said if you're looking for something purely descriptive or rather something evaluative (like **pleb**). Or if they are the same as others because they follow trends (a **sheep** or **follower**) or for some other reason. These are among at the reasons why a sample sentence would be so useful.

Comment: @SteveLovell He is looking for "a single individual or item" so noun. I also thought along the lines of *how selected* but that wasn't asked so I dropped that line of thinking.  I do agree that an example sentence would improve the question.

Comment: I *think* you're looking for something like **constituent**, **component**, or **unit**, but you need to add more detail (and that pesky example sentence!) for your question to be clear.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey, agreed but then the question title has **describes**.

Comment: @SteveLovell Ah. I think Aziz wanted "means". So two recommended changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specimen - An individual animal, plant, piece of a mineral, etc. used as an example of its species or type for scientific study or display.

> 'Carla could not help feeling a degree of reluctant admiration for
>   this odd female specimen'

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/specimen).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on context, the word **clone** might suit. One of the definitions given in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clone) online is:

> **clone**
>
> 1.1 A person or thing regarded as an exact copy of another.
>
> *‘guitarists who are labelled Hendrix clones’*

(Whatever a Hendrix may be.)

However it is a neologism, and I would not advise its use in formal writing.

Another possibility (again reflecting my scientific background) is [**instance**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/instance).

> **instance**
>
> 1 An example or single occurrence of something.
>
> *‘the search finds every instance where the word appears’*

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for a word that describes identification copies.

Comment: @Aziz — so you are after something that would indicate a member of a population. There will be technical terms for different fields (e.g. protomer in protein structure), but all I can think of in general use are idioms (e.g. man in the street, face in the crowd).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the context you mean it in, but in the network communication sense, the word you are looking for is "Anycast".

A *unicast* communication is a message from one person to one person. (one to one)

A *broadcast* communication is a message from one person to all people. (one to all)

A *multicast* communication is a message from one person to all members of a group of people. (one to many)

An ***anycast*** communication is a message from one person to *a single member* of a group of people. (one of many)

Another way of describing it is what is sometimes referred to as a phone number to a "hunt group". For instance, if I need to speak to someone in support, I can call the support "hunt group" and it will direct the call to *a single member* of the *entire support group*. If that member is unavailable, it will direct my phone call to *another single member* of the *entire support group*.

Comment: If this isn't the right context, then hopefully the above will help provide some more context in phrasing what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question I prefer the noun select or selected depending on the situation. My dictionary says the definition of selected is; to choose in preference to another or others; pick out.

Answer (score -1):

The closest definition to this word that I have found is humility. I think that I understand what the question is... As in, an employee among employees, a friend among friends, a civilian among civilians, not seeking to be better than or less than or separate from others, but just one among many. I personally don't think that humility is the best definition, but it's the closest one that I have found.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please read the question and the answers so far. Although *humility* may be a characteristic of "one of many", it's not a word for that one person, which is what is asked for.